# How can I do to pass variable throught the modals?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am working using React.js with leaflet and I have no ideas how can I do to pass variable to get when I click on my modal Eat and Drink. I mean this is what I have

[image: map]

And when I click on open modal I got that :

[image: map]

And I would like when I click on open modal above I got drink and for the other eat instead of lorem ipsum ...

Here is the code for the map :

```
import React from "react";
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import { defaultMarker } from "./defaultMarker";
import "./Map.css";

const center = [51.505, -0.09];

const data = [
  { title: "eat", coord: [50, -0.09] },
  { title: "drink", coord: [52, -0.5] }
];

const MapComp = ({ onOpen }) => {
  return (
    <Map style={{ height: "100vh" }} center={center} zoom={5}>
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
      {data.map((todo) => (
        <Marker position={todo.coord} icon={defaultMarker}>
          <Popup className="request-popup">
            <button onClick={onOpen}>Open Modal</button>
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      ))}
    </Map>
  );
};

export default MapComp;
```

And there the code for the modal :

```
import React from "react";
// import { Button, Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from "reactstrap";

export default function CustomModal({ show, onClose }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Modal isOpen={show} toggle={onClose}>
        <ModalHeader onClose={onClose}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
          aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
          reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
          pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
          culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <Button color="primary" onClick={onClose}>
            Do Something
          </Button>{" "}
          <Button color="secondary" onClick={onClose}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can find my code also here :

[My code](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-do-to-open-a-modal-using-react-leaflet-forked-1d4hv?file=/src/Modal.jsx)

How can I do that ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example codes to passing the variable.

In your app

```
export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [ variableToModel, setVariableToModel] = useState('')

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleOpen = (variable) => {
        setShow(true);
        setVariableToModel(variable)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <MapComp onOpen={handleOpen} />
      <Modal show={show} onClose={handleClose} myProp={variabletoModel} />
    </>
  );
}
```

in your map

```
 <button onClick={() => onOpen('SHOW ME IN THE MODAL'}>Open Modal</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to add some state management, this way you can add "global scopes" sharing info between components, possibilities:

- [Redux](https://redux.js.org/): use that if you have complex data.
- [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html): probably you will need to go this way, as long as you need a little state management.